# Validar uma string com Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Preciso validar o nome de um arquivo que tem o seguinte nome `NWD[0-9] PADRAO -`. A parte literal será sempre a mesma, o que pode variar são os números.

Gostaria de saber como fazer isso com *Regex*.

Comment: Então alguns exemplos seriam: "NWD0 PADRAO -", "NWD1 PADRAO -", "NWD2 PADRAO -"?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: Pessoal me deparei com um outro problema. Terei que remover essa parte do nome do arquivo e substituir por espaço em branco. Exemplo fileName.Replace("NWD1 PADRAO - ", "")     fileName.Replace("NWD2 PADRAO - ", "")     fileName.Replace("NWD3 PADRAO - ", "")                                                     Se alguém puder me ajudar mais uma vez, por favor! Agradeço desde já pela atenção!

Comment: Então significa que o nome não tem apenas `NWD0 PADRAO -` e sim outras coisas para trás ? Caso contrário ao remover essa parte fica sem nome nenhum o que não é valido para nome de um arquivo

Comment: Então, é o nome e uma data. Exemplo NWD PADRAO - 201802.xls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Regex é quase essa que você colocou na pergunta, mas acrescentando o operador "+" que indica "uma ou mais ocorrências da lista". Exemplo:

/NWD[0-9]+ PADRAO -/

[Veja aqui o exemplo em ação](https://regex101.com/r/9ysRXs/1)

Comment: Muito Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

A Regex que vai resolver seu problema é:

> `(NWD+[0-9]*)( PADRAO \-)`

Isso significa que irá buscar sempre por `NWD` seguido por caracteres de `0 a 9 um número qualquer de vezes` e por último procurará por `"espaço" PADRAO "espaco" -`

Essa regex funcionando pode ser verificada [aqui](https://regexr.com/3nqn2).

Comment: Muito obrigada!